# Racket: How do I keep an image from going off screen to appear on the other side?

Tags: racket

I'm currently making a game where your character must dodge objects going on and off the scene.

My problem is that, when the objects go off the scene, they do not reappear on the other side.

Each object is represented by a posn structure, and they move a certain distance on the scene each time there's a tick from left to right and vise versa.  I've attached which part of the code I think needs to be edited.

For clarity, a world is a `struct` containing a chicken and car, both of which are structs containing x and y posns.

And MOVE-CAR is a constant set to (add1 (random 49)) that determines how fast or slow the car will move during gameplay.

```
;update-world: world -> world

;purpose: updates the position of the car

(define (update-world a-world)
  (make-world (world-chicken a-world) (move-horiz (world-car a-world) (* -1 MOVE-CAR))))

;move-horiz: posn number -> posn

;purpose: moves the posn left or right

(define (move-horiz a-posn delta-x)
  (make-posn (+ delta-x (posn-x a-posn)) (posn-y a-posn)))
```

If more code is necessary, I will try and sift through the rest of what I have. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how can we possibly fix an issue without seeing the code, do you imagine? Could you fix my car just based on me telling you that it's supposed to move forwards, but it doesn't? Please post your code and explain its current behaviour vs the desired behaviour. Use example data if possible/relevant. We are not mind-readers and we can't see your screen.

Comment: I apologize--I'm new to Stack Overflow.  I've added some code for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the new x position, you are currently using:

```
(+ delta-x (posn-x a-posn))
```

If the result is between 0 and the width, this gives the correct result.
If the result is greater than the width, then the new x should be 0.
If the result is less    than 0, then the new x should be the width.

Let's write a function `adjust-x` that adjusts the x-position you have calculated:

```
(define WIDTH 100)

(define (adjust-x x)
   (cond 
     [(and (<= 0 x) (<= x WIDTH)) x]
     [(> x WIDTH)                 0]
     [(< x 0)                     WIDTH]
```

Then you can change `move-horiz` to:

```
(define (move-horiz a-posn delta-x)
  (make-posn (adjust-x (+ delta-x (posn-x a-posn)))
             (posn-y a-posn)))
```

Comment: I added some code from my program, and I'm not sure where what you said would fit in with what I have.  If need be, I'll paste some more of what I have.

Comment: this won't help as he may want to show only both parts on each side of screen. You need to create copy of image and draw it twice. Each for one side and correctly set x position so it looks like it is folding.

Comment: @Ondrej I changed my answer - since OP provided a code snippet.

Comment: @soegaard Thanks very much.